# Is there a workaround to define a user-defined literal for shorts in c++?

Tags: c++, user-defined-literals

I would like to define a user-defined literal for shorts. Just like this:

```
short operator"" _s(int x) 
{ 
    return (short) x; 
}
```

In order to define a short like this:

```
auto PositiveShort =  42_s;
auto NegativeShort = -42_s;
```

However, as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16596909/11539646) the C++11 Standard forbids the above implementation of the user-defined literal:

> Per paragraph 13.5.8./3 of the C++11 Standard on user-defined literals:
>   The declaration of a literal operator shall have a parameter-declaration-clause equivalent to one of the following:
>
> ```
> const char*
> unsigned long long int
> long double
> char
> wchar_t
> char16_t
> char32_t
> const char*, std::size_t
> const wchar_t*, std::size_t
> const char16_t*, std::size_t
> const char32_t*, std::size_t
> ```

For the positive case I could just use a `unsigned long long int` but this will not work for the negative case. Is there a workaround maybe using newer futures of c++?

Comment: Instead of `42_s` you could do `short(42)`.

Comment: It is actually `-(42_s)`, not `(-42)_s`.

Comment: note, `s` is already used by `<chrono>` for integers so consider using something else

Comment: @M.M Though that is without the underscore and given that you use the **std::chrono_literals** namespace so probably shouldn't be any mix-ups there.

Comment: @Evg `string` doesn't define it for integers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972812/how-do-i-define-a-negative-udl-in-c11-are-they-disallowed), the unary `-` is applied to the result of `42_s`, so it seems that integral promotion cannot be avoided. Depending on applications, the following workaround might be of some use:

```
struct Short {    
    short v;

    short operator+() const {
        return v;
    }

    short operator-() const {
        return -v;
    }
};

Short operator"" _s(unsigned long long x) { 
    return Short{static_cast<short>(x)};
}

auto PositiveShort = +42_s;
auto NegativeShort = -42_s;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(PositiveShort), short>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(NegativeShort), short>);
```